# Por qué los valores del offsetTop?

Tags: javascript

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",focusMe);
function focusMe(){
 var i = 0, d = document, inp = Array.from(d.getElementsByTagName("input")), max = inp.length,
sdiv = d.getElementById("main");

for(;i<max;i++){
  var e = inp[i];
    e.addEventListener("focus", (e)=>{
        var elemento = e.srcElement;
        sdiv.scrollTo(0, elemento.offsetTop - (sdiv.clientHeight / 2));

console.log(elemento.offsetTop)
    });
}

}
```

Por que al mostrar los valores del `offsetTop` , que me muestra la distancia en pixeles del top de su elemento padre, **no debería ser una secuencia del mismo número inicial** ? osea `8,16,24,32,40`, etc.

***Pero aveces suma 21, después más o menos, por qué?***

Comment: Que extraño, acabé de correr el ejemplo que hice en la respuesta anterior y en mi caso siempre suma 26 sin importar a que input le de el foco

Comment: Redondeo de decimales?

Comment: Suma diferentes números, como si de numeros random tratara, pero aunque sé que no son random, así lo parecen y nosé porque

Comment: @EduardoSebastian puedes decir que pretendes lograr con tu codigo? mover el scroll?

Comment: No pretendo nada, solo informarme por qué los valores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tomaste en cuenta los valores del border? o margin de cada elemento ? Te muestro un ejemplo en donde cada elemento tiene una altura de 20px, osea al dar foco en cada input debería informar una secuencia de 0,20,40,60 ...

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", focusMe);

function focusMe() {
   
  var i = 0,
    d = document,
    inp = Array.from(d.getElementsByTagName("input")),
    max = inp.length,
    sdiv = d.getElementById("main");

  for (; i < max; i++) {
    var e = inp[i];
    e.addEventListener("focus", e => {
      
      var elemento = e.srcElement;
      sdiv.scrollTo(0, elemento.offsetTop - sdiv.clientHeight / 2);

      console.log(elemento.offsetTop);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
*,*:before,*:after{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
input{
  border:0;
  height: 20px;
  width:200px;
  display:block;
  background:gray;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```